# Magento 2: luma set as default theme

Tags: magento2

is anyone have an idea about how is luma theme is setup as a default theme in fresh installation of magento 2?

is there set from file or from admin setting?
In content-configuration its said that "If no value is specified, the system default is used. The system default may be modified by third party extensions."
but where this theme has defined for make them default?

Comment: Want you luma theme as default theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's defined in the Magento_Theme modules di xml

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Theme/etc/di.xml#L65

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="frontend" xsi:type="string">Magento/luma</item>
            <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Magento/backend</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: thanks David, One more thing i have to ask that if i change this value of my custom theme then Is magento change that default theme luma to my custom theme?

Comment: Yes. This defines the default theme that is loaded when nothing else is defined in the database. So this will also load the theme in a new installation